# Is this strconv.ParseFloat() behavior expected or a bug? How can I get around it?

Tags: go

Run this code to see what I mean: [Go Playground demo of issue](https://play.golang.org/p/8qG7UcElIe)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    // From https://golang.org/src/math/const.go
    var SmallestNonzeroFloat64AsString string = "4.940656458412465441765687928682213723651e-324"
    var SmallestNonzeroFloat64 float64
    var err error
    SmallestNonzeroFloat64, err = strconv.ParseFloat(SmallestNonzeroFloat64AsString, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("SmallestNonzeroFloat64 = %g\n", SmallestNonzeroFloat64)
    fmt.Printf("SmallestNonzeroFloat64 = %s\n", strconv.FormatFloat(SmallestNonzeroFloat64, 'f', -1, 64))
}
```

`SmallestNonzeroFloat64` is defined in [math/const.go](https://golang.org/src/math/const.go) and I assumed it can be represented by a float64 variable.

But when it is parsed into a float64 with `strconv.ParseFloat()` and printed with `strconv.FormatFloat()` the result is rounded.

Instead of `4.940656458412465441765687928682213723651e-324` I get `5e-324` (or its non-exponent equivalent, which you can see in the Go Playground results). The result is rounded.

Is there a way to get back the `4.940656458412465441765687928682213723651e-324`?

Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 7):

## This is not a bug.

You could ask Go to print more digits.

```
fmt.Printf("SmallestNonzeroFloat64 = %.40g\n", SmallestNonzeroFloat64)
// 4.940656458412465441765687928682213723651e-324
```

However, `5e-324` and `4.94…e-324` are in fact the same value, so Go is not wrong printing `5e-324`. This value (2<sup>-1074</sup>) is the smallest positive number representable by Float64 (also known as `double` in other languages). Larger numbers are all multiples of this, e.g. the next smallest number would be 2 × 2<sup>-1074</sup> = `1e-323`, the next would be 3 × 10<sup>-1074</sup> = `1.5e-323`, etc.

In the other words, all numbers more precise than `5e-324` would not be representable in Float64. So it makes no sense to print more digit after the "5". And `5e-324` is certainly more readable than `4.94…e-324`.

Comment: That clarifies. A few more lines of code helps confirm: [link](https://play.golang.org/p/j-a-wSXIGt)